# Middle Border Ideas, underline middle

Tags: alignment, border

How would you create this in raw HTML / CSS?

> [image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

div {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    width: 50px;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

It doesn't look like you can apply a text-decoration to a div. Which would make sense because it is not text. Are there any border middle features?

Answer (score 1):

I just answered a similar scenario here [text of indeterminate length and line in HTML/CSS the "right" way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28755194/text-of-indeterminate-length-and-line-in-html-css-the-right-way/28755245#28755245)

A solution, as above, could be to have a span within the div or heading that has a background set in the :before or :after pseudo element and then the text within the span can sit on top with a white background. Hope this solves your problem and answers your question.

http://jsfiddle.net/7o6c4gvg/

```
h3 {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
h3:after {
    content:"";
    height:1px;
    width:100%;
    background: #000;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:0;
}
h3 span {
    background:#fff;
    display:table;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    z-index:9;   
}
```